# Laravel - Repository Pattern issues

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

I've got my Laravel application using the repository pattern. I also have an abstract class called `EloquentRepository` which contains basic methods. All of my repositories have an `update()` method, where I simply update a model using an ID and array:

```
abstract class EloquentRepository {

    public function update($id, array $array) {
        $this->model->whereId($id)->update($array);
    }

}
```

Now, I also have a `Server` repository:

```
interface ServerRepository {

   public function update($id, array $options);

}

class EloquentServerRepository extends EloquentRepository implements ServerRepository {

    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Server $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

So now, I don't have to add the `update()` method to my `EloquentServerRepository`, nor any other Repositories which need to do this (quite a few).

However, there is one repository which does have an update feature, but I'd like it to do something "custom". Lets say it's the User repository:

```
interface UserRepository {

   public function update($id, array $options, $status);

}

class EloquentUserRepository extends EloquentRepository implements UserRepository {

    protected $model;

    public function __construct(User $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function update($id, array $options, $status)
    {
        $this->model->setStatus($status);
        $this->model->whereId($id)->update($options);
    }
}
```

So now, I have my User repository requiring a status with every update.

However, I get the error:

`Declaration of EloquentUserRepository::update() should be compatible with EloquentRepository::update($id, array $array)`.

Why is this, surely my interface specifies what the declaration should be?

Answer (score 1):

You can get passed that error by making $status optional by giving it default value, for example:

```
public function update($id, array $options, $status = null)
```

Without it being optional (with default value) you're saying this method needs to have a third parameter, which violates the contract set by `ServerRepository`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are extending `EloquentUserRepository` where you have the `update` method like this:

```
public function update($id, array $array) {
    $this->model->whereId($id)->update($array);
}
```

In this case you are also implementing the `UserRepository` interface but according to the base class' `update` method your `update` method has a different signature, which is as given below:

```
public function update($id, array $options, $status);
```

So, the error is rising because you've different method signatures. While you may can make both method's signature same probably using an optional parameter like this:

```
// EloquentUserRepository
public function update($id, array $array, $status = null) {
    $this->model->whereId($id)->update($array);
}

// interface UserRepository
interface UserRepository {
    public function update($id, array $options, $status = null);
}
```

But I would suggest to use only one interface or abstract class and override the method in your `EloquentUserRepository` for  the different use case. Which would look like this:

```
abstract class EloquentRepository {
    public function update($id, array $array, $status = null) {
        $this->model->whereId($id)->update($array);
    }
}

// Only extend the EloquentRepository and override the update method
class EloquentUserRepository extends EloquentRepository {

    protected $model;

    public function __construct(User $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    // re-declare the method to override
    public function update($id, array $options, $status = null)
    {
        $this->model->setStatus($status);
        $this->model->whereId($id)->update($options);
    }
}
```

Or change `EloquentRepository` a little, for example:

```
abstract class EloquentRepository {

    public function update($id, array $array, $status = null) {

        if(!is_null($status)) {
            $this->model->setStatus($status);
        }

        $this->model->whereId($id)->update($array);
    }
}
```